# Checking characters in string in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am creating a validator for inputs on one of my text fields in java. The length of the input field should be 10 and the values should be any number in between 1-9. The catch is, the input should use the same character only 10x... So valid values should be such as the following:

```
1111111111
2222222222
....
9999999999
```

But if the entered text is something like 111111112, this should be considered as invalid entry.

Currently I use String.matches("^[0-9]+$") to check if the inputted values are valid but this still accepts 111111112 as valid. What is the correct approach to check if all 10 characters of the string is the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using back referencing:

```
String.matches("^([0-9])\1{9}$")
```

or:

```
String.matches("^([0-9])\\1{9}$")
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/lK0dB5)

This only matches exactly 10 digits in a line that are *all* the same.

Comment: That was fast, sshashank! +1 :)

Comment: @zx81, Thank you. :). We meet again

Comment: Now you made me laugh... Thanks for that. :) Catch you later, starting to watch a show.